# Exception : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object. exception for the following code. I can prevent this by creating an instance of RequestDetail and then passing ObjectId ot that.

But whats wrong with this code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Request header = new Request();
        header.RequestDetail.ObjectId = "12343";

        RequestDetail rd = new RequestDetail();
        rd = header.RequestDetail;

        Console.WriteLine(rd.ObjectId);
    }
}

public class Request
{
    public RequestDetail RequestDetail { get; set; }
}
public class RequestDetail
{
    public string ObjectId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Request header = new Request { RequestDetail = new RequestDetail() }
```

or you can initialize the RequestDetail in the Request constructor as well.

Comment: You can assing values to properties in this way too. Here is some "explanation": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
Request header = new Request();
header.RequestDetail.ObjectId = "12343";
```

If the constructor of `Request` does not initialize `this.RequestDetail` (or initializes it to `null`), you'll get a `NullReferenceException` when you try to access `Request.RequestDetail` properties.

So, initialize it in your constructor.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `Request` does not initialize its `RequestDetail` member in the constructor (in fact, it has no constructor at all).

If you expect to be able to access `RequestDetail` right after constructing your `Request`, you should add a constructor, like this:

```
public class Request {
    public RequestDetail RequestDetail { get; set; }
    public Request() {
        RequestDetail = new RequestDetail();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `ObjectId` from the property `RequestDetail` before initializing it, so the value of the latter is `Null`.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do - maybe something like this?:

```
Request header = new Request();
RequestDetail rd = new RequestDetail();    
rd.ObjectId = "12343";
header.RequestDetail = rd;

Console.WriteLine(rd.ObjectId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not initializing RequestDetail before invoking the property. You could do something like:

```
public class Request {
    public Request(){
        this.RequestDetail = new RequestDetail();
    }
    public RequestDetail RequestDetail { get; set; }
}
public class RequestDetail{
    public string ObjectId { get; set; }
}
```